# Symfony 3 - SwiftMail - renderView for the body

Tags: function, symfony, email, static

I want to send n mail with swiftmail on symfony 3.4
I would use the -> setBody ($ this-> renderView ("....") for the content of the mail.

Only, I have two problems. The first is that my function using swiftMail is a static function, so you have to use self :: instead of $ this->, but the self :: renderView does not work.

On the other hand, I do not understand in what form should I put my link pointing, I find everything on the internet, and I do not know which to take

For the moment, I've :

```
$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();

        // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                        ->setSubject($subject)
                        ->setFrom(array($mailFrom => 'aliasTest'))
                        ->setTo($emailAdress)
                        ->setCharset('utf-8')
                        ->setContentType('text/html')
                        ->setBody("hello"); // ->setBody(self::renderView(" ???")

        $mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go one of two ways here:

- make the function non-static in a controller / maybe extract it into a service
- provide the body or the renderer as a parameter to the function.

If you remove it from the/a controller, a twig environment (`\Twig_Environment $twig`)  can be used (`$twig->render('templatename', $paramarray)`).

(Disclaimer: the `\Twig_Environment` may be called differently / have a proper namespace in your version of twig ;o))